# Aurelia not dirty checking function result in HTML class attribute binding

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I have a table row that a user can select by clicking on it or by going to a URL (router parameters gets checked on view-model activation). The markup looks like

```html
<!--...-->
<template repeat.for="foo of foos">
  <template repeat.for="bar of foo.bars">
    <tr class="${(foo.pk == selectedFoo && bar.pk == selectedBar) ? 'active' : ''}" click.delegate="selectFooBar(foo.pk, bar.pk)"><!--...--></tr>
  </template>
</template>
<!--...-->
```

This works fine. When the user clicks, `selectFooBar` sets the view-model parameters and the class gets set on the `tr`.

However, I tried refactoring the conditional into a method (the conditional will get more complex):

```html
<tr class="${isFooBarSelected(foo.pk, bar.pk) ? 'active' : ''}" click.delegate="selectFooBar(foo.pk, bar.pk)"><!--...--></tr>
```

`isFooBarSelected` just returns true/false based on the conditional. However, now the method is not being checked after page load. When the selected parameters change (because the user clicks on another row), the class does not get updated. Any ideas how to make Aurelia dirty check `isFooBarSelected`?

---

## View-Model

```js
export class Blah {

  foo = [];
  selectedFoo = undefined;
  selectedBar = undefined;

  // ...

  /**
   * Lifecycle method - just before view-model is displayed
   * @param params route parameters
   */
  activate(params) {
    this.selectedFoo = params.foo;
    this.selectedBar = params.bar;
  }

  selectFooBar(foo, bar) {
    this.selectedFoo = foo;
    this.selectedBar = bar;
  }

  isFooBarSelected(foo, bar) {
    console.log('check', foo, bar, this.selectedFoo, this.selectedBar);
    return foo == this.selectedFoo && bar == this.selectedBar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't pass `selectedFoo` and `selectedBar` to the function, then Aurelia isn't going to know to call the function when their values change. Given that those two values are what will actually change the return value of the function (for a given `foo.pk` and `bar.pk`), you will have to pass those.

Aurelia tries to be smart and not do dirty checking on functions. It assumes the functions you call in a situation like this are pure functions and that their return value will only change if one of the inputs changes.

So just change the function to:

```
isFooBarSelected(foo, bar, selectedFoo, selectedBar) {
  console.log('check', foo, bar, this.selectedFoo, this.selectedBar);
  return foo == selectedFoo && bar == selectedBar;
}
```

and the usage to

```
${isFooBarSelected(foo.pk, bar.pk, selectedFoo, selectedBar) ? 'active' : ''}
```

and everything will work as expected.